# What can I use to replace old asbestos-based siding with a similar look?

Tags: shingles

I went to Menards and Lowes.  I can't find a way to buy some of these for the outside of the house.  These are asbestos, but I thought they might make updated ones.

[image]

Comment: Look for(google) fire resistant siding/shingles.  Asbestos has a bad name.

Answer (score 3):

Closest thing to asbestos siding you can get new is fiber cement siding.  You can get textures like the one in your picture, it looks pretty good for repairs.  It's widely available, you probably just didn't know what to look for

Answer (score 3):

Since the question is "Where I can buy these?", the answer is "nowhere", since the sale of shingles with asbestos is illegal.

However, if you want to buy something similar, go to your local builders' supply house and request a sampler of fiber cement siding. They might have something that matches the exact dimensions, texture and color.

Be aware that builders' supply stores do not advertise, are always out of the way (think of industrial areas near highways, not strip malls), and open at 6:00am. If you call them to ask for hours and the guy at the other end of the line barks at you, you've probably found the right place. Just go in person.

Comment: From what I have seen online, asbestos products is not yet banned in the US(federal)  as it is in other countries.  If I am mistaken, sorry.

Comment: @crip659 I know that you can still buy products with asbestos in the US for industrial processes, but I can't think of anything that is related to houses.

Comment: That might be a store/insurance/scare of lawsuits not selling thing instead of being illegal.  Which does the same thing.